# Using Media Foundation API to disable specific decoders

Tags: c++, .net, ms-media-foundation

I have a project which has Windows Media Player embedded. Using the `Media Foundation API`, how do I disable mp4 and mkv file formats? So Windows Media Player will use third-party decoders for mp4 and mkv file formats instead. (Which in my case is `FFDSHOW`, I want to use its `H264` decoder for mp4 and mkv file formats instead of `Media Foundation` decoders).

I heard that there's a third-party software named `Codec Tweak Tool` which does the job, probably it's using `Media Foundation API` to achieve that.

Using `Codec Tweak Tool` and a Win registry debugger I found out a few registry directories which may be related to `Media Foundation`.

I tried to change a registry in the following Win registry directory: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Media Foundation\ByteStreamHandlers\.mkv` (Windows 10 64-Bit directory), but the system doesn't give me permission, using registry seems like a hacky way to change it though, I get access denied by the way. I don't think that's the right way to do it. I heard that I can achieve the same by using the `Media Foundation API`, maybe using `Media Foundation Transforms` or a `Source Resolver`, but I don't know how to set a proper object and work with the API interfaces to do such a thing. However I know that after disabling it, I should set a preferred directShow decoder such as `FFDSHOW` so it'll be used instead of the `Media Foundation` for those respective file formats which I'm suppose to disable.

After using `Codec Tweak Tool` to change `H264` preferred decoder, I found out which registries are changed after setting a preferred directShow decoder.

Key directory:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DirectShow\Preferred` (Windows 10 64-Bit directory)

Registries that have been chaged:

```
{31435641-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
{34363248-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
{34363268-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
```

and applied the following `FFDSHOW` `CLSID` to each of them: `{04FE9017-F873-410E-871E-AB91661A4EF7}`

I also noticed that the `CLSID` is required to set a preferred decoder.

I've come to the conclusion that working with registry is definitely not the right way to achieve that, so how to do that by using the `Media Foundation API`? I've read the [Media Foundation API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) but it seems confusing for me due to the low level and complexity it takes.

Comment: You can try to use MFRegisterLocalByteStreamHandler with a custom  byte stream handler, but you must have a COM object that understand how to play with Media Foundation. You can't use an exe for example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfapi/nf-mfapi-mfregisterlocalbytestreamhandler

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the heads up. I noticed a pointer to the `IMFActivate` interface, however I don't know what COM object implements that interface, could you show off an example of how to instantiate that COM object and pass that interface to `MFRegisterLocalByteStreamHandler` function?

Comment: Don't know any official sample, but you have one here (c# but it's the same stuff) https://github.com/ajorkowski/VirtualSpace/blob/master/VideoDecoders.MediaFoundation/DecoderRegister.cs

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you very much for that sample, it gives a good idea how to achieve that, however since it's in C# I have a lot of work to do in order to convert it to C++ also provide the MP4 handlers, notice that I'll need a lot of classes from that project, those are a lot of files related to achieve it, so I don't see a simple answer for this question.

Comment: Indeed, it's quite a work if you don't have an already available stream handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the correspondive bytestream handler registry key by first changing the owner rights from Trusted Installer to Administrators and then give Administrators 'full access'- or 'edit subkey'-rights to the registry key object  by right-clicking on the key entry in windows registry editors left window.
After that, don't forget to reset the access rights to 'read only'...